# How to make a sql instance public from an EC2 VM?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've got a brand new EC2 VM in AWS and installed SQL Server on it. I've then imported a database and now want to make that data externally accessible.
Can anyone guide me as to what I need to do?

Dont worry this isn't anything sensitive, its just test content at the moment.

Thus far I've turned off the Windows Firewall to ensure that wasn't blocking it, ensured TCP/IP is enabled in SQL but when I try and connect to it from an asp.net application for example (either locally or from an asp.net app running on a different ec2 instance), it just times out connecting (using the public DNS or the private IP adddress of the VM).

What are the steps that I realistically need to do to make this SQL instance available outside of the VM?

Comment: Did you open SQL Server port 1433 on the security group?

Comment: Felipe - DOH. Forgot to add the rule to the security group. Feel free to update as an answer and I'll mark it as so. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you add services to your EC2 instance you need to make sure to allow inbound connections to the needed ports in the security group attached to your instance.

Did you open the port 1433 to allow inbound connections to Microsoft SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some basic steps to troubleshooting SQL Server Connectivity:

1. Is SQL Server running, and on TCP/IP
2. From the client can you PING
3. From the client can you TELNET  1433

Can you clarify the network setup, is it like this:

VM > VM HOST > CLIENT on LAN

VM > VM HOST > CLIENT on Internet

Try those troubleshooting steps at each stage.